# Difference between HTML tables and CSS tables?

Tags: html, css

What exactly is the difference between HTML tables:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
```

and CSS tables?

```
display: table
display: table-row
display: table-cell
```

Comment: What exactly does this have to do with JavaScript?

Comment: One is markup, the other is styling.

Comment: "here's a hammer. here's a piece of paper that says 'hammer'".

Comment: Forget HTML tables, unless you are displaying tabular data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An HTML table describes a data structure where each item in a row has something in common with each other and where each item in a column has something in common with each other.

A CSS table describes how to lay out a set of elements in rows and columns.

The default CSS applied to an HTML table is a CSS table.

Comment: There’s a lot more, like the fact that HTML tables can have cells spanning several rows or columns, CSS tables cannot.